# How can I read an input field on my own website and store the data entered on my server in a txt document?

Tags: javascript, html

I host a website via my Nas and would like to read an input field and then save it as a txt on my server after a button has been pressed.

I don't have much php knowledge yet and wanted to ask if this is also possible via javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is English only so please translate your question. Willkommen bei Stackoverflow. Fragen auf Stackoverflow müssen auf englisch gestellt werden, also bitte übersetze deine Frage.

Comment: Even a translated version of this won't be answerable as is though. We'd need a lot more information, and you to try something more.

Comment: Bitte lesen Sie auch die Hilfe, um zu verstehen, wie Sie eine gute Frage schreiben, bei der wir Ihnen helfen können. (Please also read the help to understand how to write a good question that we can help you with.)